# What was the city of El Mirador called in Mayan?

Tags: maya

[El Mirador](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Mirador) was a major city in the Yucatan during the Preclassic Mayan era.  The name is obviously Spanish.  What was it called by the ancient Maya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an (excellent) article on Smithsonian.com titled, [El Mirador, the Lost City of the Maya](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/history-archaeology/El-Mirador-the-Lost-City-of-the-Maya.html?c=y&page=5):

> Hansen believes that El Mirador’s inhabitants may have initially gone to the Caribbean coast and then migrated back inland, where they finally ended up in Mexico’s Yucatán Peninsula at Calakmul, which emerged as a powerful city-state and rival to Tikal in the sixth and seventh centuries. “**Mirador was known in the Preclassic as the Kan Kingdom—Kan meaning ‘snake’**—and the kings of [Calakmul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calakmul) referred to themselves as the Lords of Kan, not as the Lords of Chiik Naab, which is the original name of Calakmul,” Hansen said.